# Post-apocalyptic sci-fi book about intelligent war machines

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

It's a post-apocalyptic sci-fi book from the early eighties about no humans left but the intelligent war machines keep fighting on. I think it focuses in on one machine named Lucy or something. Its excerpt was in the same magazine that previewed Arnold Schwarzenegger's first Terminator movie. But I don't know if that was a sci-fi or military gun or armor magazine.

Comment: It might have been called entropy pump but not sure.

Comment: That issue might have been Soldier of Fortune, the December 1984 issue (https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/0a/60/04/0a6004ef13a9a3ff67acb969576de483.jpg).

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! Feel free to take the [Science Fiction & Fantasy tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand our site better. You can also visit [How to ask a good question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) together with this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/) and subsequently add more details to your question so that it will be easier for others to find the book you are searching for.

Comment: The defunct military magazine from the 1980's was called "International Combat Arms," published by the same folks who do "Guns and Ammo" but also covering ground, air, sea, and space weaponry beyond just small arms. They printed a short story about an intelligent ground robot fighting a war in North America. As I remember it, the fighting machines were loosely controlled by a human operator called The User who sometimes praised his machine when they did well. Fiction appeared in the magazine rarely. The story was said to be taken from a novel called "The Entropy Pump".

Comment: Sounds similar to a Phillip K. Dick short story, [Second Variety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Variety "Second Variety"), which was chilling and fun. Might want to check that one out if you're interested in this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

I remember this article as well, but unfortunately no longer have the magazine.  It was an article on the potential use of robots in warfare. Excerpts from "The Entropy Pump" were spaced throughout the article.

As I recall "The Entropy Pump" was stated to be an 'upcoming novel', so I suspect it was either never published or done so under a different name.

Could it have been written by Joe Poyer?  http://www.monobrowze.co.uk/joepoyer/ He wrote several sci-fi stories and military articles, and there was a Joe Poyer who also wrote articles for International Combat Arms.  Don't know if they are the same person.

I've been trying to remember which edition of the magazine it was.  I saw a photograph of ICA with a Prowler robot (think the one Chuck Norris has backing him up in "Code of Silence") on the cover that I think may be the one.  Unfortunately the photo was too blurred to make out the month and year, or what articles were inside.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Could you [edit] this to expand on how this matches the OPs description? It is also not entirely clear if you are iding this as "The Entropy Pump" or an article from a magazine. Again could you edit to clarify this?

Comment: It was an article on the potential use of robots in warfare. Excerpts from this 'upcoming novel", which I also remember as being called "The Entropy Pump" were spaced throughout the article. I can't remember if the article was in Soldier of Fortune magazine, but I did read a lot of SOF at the time and even remember owning the one in the link with the Terminator on the cover.

Comment: Please don't submit edits without proofreading them for spelling and typos.